# Cos'è un "ventaglio a stecche"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, vocabulary

Nel racconto *I meteoriti*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Mia moglie agitava un *ventaglio a stecche* per smuovere l'aria sempre un po' polverulenta attorno ai nostri visi; io reggevo, a ripararci da possibili raffiche di pioggia meteorica, un ombrello.

So cos'è un "ventaglio" e so anche cos'è una "stecca", ma non capisco il significato di "ventaglio a stecche". Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Non credo di aver mai visto un ventaglio senza stecche, magari ce ne sono, comunque sono piuttosto sicuro che indichi quello che s'intende nell'accezione comune con semplice "ventaglio": http://cdn-2.faidatemania.it/o/j/come-costruire-un-ventaglio_7c71786023d93d53a0012fd67a6f47a2.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ho trovato questo [link](http://www.ilventaglio.org/tipi__di__ventagli.htm): il ventaglio a stecche, come prevedibile, è quello che si può "richiudere", proprio perchè è formato dalle stecche, che ne permettono l'"estensione". L'altro tipo viene invece chiamato "ventaglio rigido" (nel link che ho messo).
Tuttavia, come ben saprai, al giorno d'oggi, quasi tutti i ventagli rientrano nella prima categoria. Pertanto, quando si usa il termine "ventaglio" in una conversazione attuale, si fa quasi sempre riferimento a quello "a stecche". Quindi, per un italiano madrelingua, il termine "ventaglio a stecche" usato in una conversazione risulta leggermente fuori luogo.

[image: Ventaglio a stecche]
[image: Ventaglio rigido]